# connected graphs with largest eigenvalue greater than 2

Tags: graph-theory

I work on a variation of the dollar game. This game is known to end after a finite number of firing iff the graph is a Smith graph. These graphs are also known as the famous and ubiquitous ADE graphs (2 infinite families of graphs, the $A_n$ et $D_n$  graphs and 3 exceptional graphs $E_6, E_7, E_8$. The J.H Smith theorem asserts that these are the only connected graphs with largest eigenvalue strictly less than 2.

If we accept that maximum eigenvalue is 2 we get the extended Smith graphs with one more node. Still a finite number.

My question is:

If I relax the condition and accept max eigenvalue in the range $(2;2 + \epsilon)$ do I get an infinity of graphs whatever the positive $\epsilon$ is?

Thanks for any help